# CSharp Code Generator gives System.PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, code-generation, csharpcodeprovider

So I have this simple generator just for test purposes:

```
        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var options = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = false, 
            GenerateInMemory = true
        };
        
        string code = "using System;namespace Expression{public static class Expression{public static void Test() {var foo = 2}}}";
        
        var result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, code);
```

But Whenever I run it gives me `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.`

**Note** I am targeting net5.0-windows (do not know if this is relevant to the error)